# Finding Magnetic Mirroring Points

Tags: plasma-physics

I am trying to find the mirroring points of the following magnetic field.

$B_z = 2B_0[1+(\frac{z}{L})^2]$

This is problem 3.13 taken from Introduction to Plasma Physics by Donald A. Gurnett (Second Ed.). What I don't understand is that it tells us to use the second invariant...

$J= \int_{a}^{b} v_{parallel} \,dS$

...which in this case is just a path integral in one dimension (z). But the bounds for the integral are the mirror locations themselves (At least that is what I read in the book). This seems counterintuitive to me, because how am I supposed to use a formula that requires the thing I am trying to solve for? Please help me understand, I am very lost.

Full problem statement:

3.13 A particle is trapped in a magnetic mirror field given by

$B_z = B_0[1+(\frac{z}{L})^2]$

Initially, the mirror points of the particle are located at $z=+/-L$

(a) $B_0$ is now slowly increased to $2B_0$. Using the second adiabatic invariant, find the new mirror point locations and the new mirror field $B_m$.

(b) L is then slowly decreased to L/2, while holding $2B_0$ constant. Using the second adiabatic invariant, find the new mirror point locations and the new mirror field $B_m$.

Comment: Can you describe the initial condition and geometry in more detail please? Without resorting to the integral, I think you can find the locations where the velocity vector is $\perp$ to $z$. Remember that the magnetic field does no work.

Comment: @Newbie I wrote the full problem into the post now. Yeah, it should be that and I think I could solve the problem another way using that knowledge, but what I don't understand is using the requested specific way to solve it.

Comment: I just went through page 56 of the book, equation (3.8.20) from that page + the explanations on that page should help you solve the problem. Choose $a=-b$ to add symmetry to your problem and the fact that $B_{z}$ is an even function with respect to $z$ and that will help with the integration.

Comment: Conserve kinetic energy and hold the magnetic moment (1st adiabatic invariant) constant.  Solve for when the kinetic energy is described as only having velocities orthogonal to the magnetic field.